# Changing javascript string literals with Rhino

Tags: java, javascript, escaping, rhino, google-closure-compiler

i'm writing a custom compiler pass for Closure that switches javascript literal strings to hex. So `"a"` becomes `"\x61"`

but the code:

```
node.setString("\\x61");
```

results in javascript like this:

```
"\\x61"
```

instead of:

```
"\x61"
```

Of course, if I only use one slash in my java code, then it won't compile. The same is true with `\n`. It seems that somewhere behind the scenes, Closure / Rhino is automatically escaping the strings. But I can't find where. How can I write a string with special chars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this would have to be done during output (code printing). Internally the string will be represented in it's unescaped form. Take a look at the [Code Generator](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CodeGenerator.java).